# IllegalArgumentException in java code

Tags: java, runtimeexception

I have written a code for the problem:

> Three numbers A, B and C are the inputs. Write a program to find
>   second largest among three numbers. Input
>
> The first line contains an integer T, total number of testcases. Then
>   follow T lines, each line contains three integers A, B and C. Output
>
> Display the second largest among A, B and C. Constraints
>
> 1 ≤ T ≤ 1000 1 ≤ A,B,C ≤ 1000000 Example
>
> Input:

```
3  
120 11 400 
10213 312 10 
10 3 450
```

> Expected Output:

```
120 
312 
10
```

I get an ***IllegalArgumentException***. I am not able to understand how I should remove the exception:

```
  import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class trial2
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a,b,c;
        int ctr=1;
            int t=in.nextInt();
            while(ctr<=t){
            a=in.nextInt();
            b=in.nextInt();
            c=in.nextInt();
            if((a>b&&b>c)||(a<b&&b<c))
            System.out.println(b);
            else if((b<a&&a<c)||(b>a&&a>c))
            System.out.println(a);
            else if((a>c&&c>b)||(a<c&&c<b))
            System.out.println(c);
            ctr++;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your stack trace.

Comment: I didnt get you @shmosel

Comment: not understanding why you are doing multiple `readLine` when there seems to be a single line of input?

Comment: @shmosel - he does not print his stacktrace, just `error` - ho hum

Comment: One of the Long.parseLong(buf.readLine()); is causing your exception, you have only one line, but you are reading more than one line. Also, consider using Scanner instead of the BufferedReader. Scanner has method like nextInt() which you can use to get the next integer input

Comment: @ScaryWombat so what is the alternative simply buf.read??

Comment: @Partha has given you the answer

Comment: @Partha 
`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
 at trial2.main(Main.java:13)`

Comment: You are going to have to update your question, we can not just guess the code.  Also you do not need all the preamble in your question.

Comment: do a hasNextInt() check before you do a nextInt()